# Проверить массив при помощи библиотеки assert

Tags: c++, тестирование, динамические-массивы

Использую библиотеку assert для тестов функций.
Есть функция, которая удаляет повторяющиеся подряд элементы.
Т.е. делает из массива {4, 4, 3, 4} массив {4, 3, 4}.
Необходимо использовать assert, чтобы проверить некоторый массив на совпадение с ожидаемым результатом:

```
double *d = new double[Len] {4, 4, 3, 4}; // Результат {4, 3, 4}
CheckAndDel(d, Len); // Удаляет повторяющиеся элементы
FixSize(Len, d); // Делает массив длинной 3
assert( d = { 4, 3, 4 } ); // Нерабочая строка
```

Как реализовать проверку в 4 строке?

Comment: Сравнение поэлементно через `&&`

Answer (score 1):

Что-то типа

```
int * d = new int[4] { 4, 4, 3, 4 };
auto check_array = [](int*d,initializer_list<int>x){ for(auto i: x) if (*d != i) return false; return true; };

assert(check_array(d,{4,4,3}));
assert(check_array(d,{4,3,4}));
```

:)

Да, еще - как понимать вашу проверку - как то, что первые три элемента вот такие (как сделано у меня)? потому что длина массива `d` вообще-то неизвестна...